# Getting Facebook GraphResponse JSON Objects

Tags: android, json, facebook

I used this lines of code in Facebook Sdk 3.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        new Request(
                session,
                "/" + user_ID + "/likes",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {


                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
    ....
```

Now, they added the GraphResponse that hasn`t the same methods to parse the JSON.

How do I get the same JsonArray of objects with this code:

```
    new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + user_ID + "/likes",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                try {
// my code

            }
        }).executeAsync();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `graphResponse.getJSONObject()` or `graphResponse.getJSONArray()` as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphResponse/).

The response JSON for `/me/likes` should look something like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "id": "43110923010",
      "created_time": "2014-11-19T23:45:46+0000"
      ...
    },
    ...]
}
```